# how to display login_required_message in django

Tags: python, django

I want to display login_required message like **you have to login first to give the review** while redirecting to the login page. How can i achieve this.

> views.py

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='next',login_url='shop:users_signin')
def review(request,slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
            review.user = request.user
            review.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Review Saved.')
            return redirect('shop:detail', slug)
    else:
        return redirect('shop:detail',slug)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@login_required` decorator is for convenience but doesn't make it easy to customise the behaviour. If you use CBVs, the `LoginRequiredMixin` makes it easier, because you can override `handle_no_permission()` to add a message to the `request` before the redirect occurs.

So the best alternative you have if you use simple function based views it to write the authentication check yourself:

```
 def review(request, slug):
     if not request.user.is_authenticated:
         messages.info("You need to be logged in in order to give a review")
         return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
     # rest of your view here
```

And then in your login template make sure you display the message.

Comment: what should we have to mention in request.path

Comment: `request.path` is the current path so you want to pass it as `next` parameter to the login view so that after login, the user returns to the current page (your `review` view)